# How to match column data to another column in a different table

Tags: oracle

I have  a table called **txn_detail** which has the primary key **txn_id** and an Advance Queue table called **hlr_pre_qt** that has the Primary Key of **txn_detail** inside a column called **user_data** with several other values separated by commas. I need to filter them out and make a mapping between the two tables using these two columns (txn_detail.txn_id and hlr_pre_qt.user_data). How can i do this?

[image: txn_detail table]

[image: hlr_pre_qt queue table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like to do the join
i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM txn_detail A
    JOIN hlr_pre_qt B on B.user_data.txn_id = A.txn_id
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM txn_detail A
    JOIN hlr_pre_qt B on b.USER_DATA LIKE '%' || TO_CHAR(A.txn_id) || '%'
```

OR

You can strip the TXN_ID from user_data....

```
SELECT *
FROM txn_detail A
    JOIN hlr_pre_qt B on 
        SUBSTR(b.USER_DATA, INSTR(b.USER_DATA, '(') +1, INSTR(b.USER_DATA, ',') - INSTR(b.USER_DATA, '(') - 1) = TO_CHAR(A.txn_id)
```

In both cases, no index will be used to do the join, so performance will be poor.

Hope that helps

Comment: It gives me "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got ABS_INP.TASK_TYP" the hlr_pre_qt.user_data has a user defined data type. Anyway to get through this?

Comment: Gives me the same error... Sorry for the trouble but i'm a newbie to Oracle. :)

Comment: Can you post the definition of ABS_INP.TASK_TYP

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found another way. The user_data column is partitioned into several columns. So i could access them in the following manner, "hlr_pre_qt.user_data.txn_id". Sorry i couldn't find the definition since the sources are wrapped.